# Debugging navtivescript vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm *really* new to developing an Android app using NativeScript Vue.

I'm struggling to understand what the debugging capabilities are.  I have created a sample project using the template https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template) and have read about vue devtools.  I'm wanting to put breakpoints in my JavaScript somewhere (in Chrome?) so I can step through my code, I just can't work out if this is possible?

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `tns debug [ios|android]`?

This will by default initiate a debugger with Chrome Dev Tools. You will see a URL in console once app is launched in your Simulator / Device, just have hit that with Chrome.